# Print all possible combinations with limit restrictions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, combinations

I have a group of multidimensional arrays that consist of a food and a price for that food. The user enters foods and their price and these are put in the arrays. I know the arrays are successfully populating from the what the user enters because I have tested it by printing it out. That piece of code is still in my example but can be ignored. But what I need to do is print out the possible combinations of meals that are under a limited amount of money and the meal must have 1 piece of meat, 2 fruits, 3 vegetables, and 1 pasta. I can't figure out how to make it work. I know I need to parse the prices of the food to use them for the math. I appreciate any help.

```
    public static void fillarrays(){
    String meatarray [][] = {{meat1,meat2,meat3},{meatprice1,meatprice2,meatprice3}};
    String fruitarray [][] = {{fruit1,fruit2,fruit3,fruit4,fruit5,fruit6},{fruitprice1,fruitprice2,fruitprice3,fruitprice4,fruitprice5,fruitprice6}};
    String vegetablearray [][] = {{veg1,veg2,veg3,veg4,veg5,veg6,veg7,veg8},{vegprice1,vegprice2,vegprice3,vegprice4,vegprice5,vegprice6,vegprice7,vegprice8}};
    String pastaarray [][] = {{pasta1,pasta2,pasta3,pasta4},{pastaprice1,pastaprice2,pastaprice3,pastaprice4}};

    System.out.println("Meat");
    displayarray(meatarray);
    System.out.println("Fruit");
    displayarray(fruitarray);
    System.out.println("Vegetables");
    displayarray(vegetablearray);
    System.out.println("Pasta");
    displayarray(pastaarray);

}

public static void displayarray(String x[][]){
    for(int row=0; row<x.length; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<x[row].length; column++){
            System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t\t" );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: psst... OO is the way to go, then you wouldn't have to deal with multidimensional arrays

Comment: You could use 8 nested loops lol... OO is indeed the way to go

Comment: How can I use OO to make it better.. could you give me an example by chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
long maxPrice = // ...
for(int m = 0 ; m < meatarray[1].length ; ++m) {
  if(meatarray[1][m] <= maxPrice) {
    for(int f = 0 ; f < fruitarray[1].length ; ++f) {
      if(meatarray[1][m] + fruitarray[1][f] <= maxPrice) {
        for(int v = 0 ; v < vegetablearray[1].length ; ++v) {
          if(meatarray[1][m] + fruitarray[1][f] + vegetablearray[1][v] <= maxPrice) {
            for(int p = 0 ; v < pastaarray[1].length ; ++p) {
              if(meatarray[1][m] + fruitarray[1][f] + vegetablearray[1][v]
                 + pastaarray[1][p] <= maxPrice) {
                System.out.println(meatarray[0][m] + " " + fruitarray[0][f] + " "
                  + vegetablearray[0][v] + " " + pastaarray[0][p]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will allow me to select 2 from the fruit and 3 from the vegetables as well?